# Azure ARM Template with Conditions for Private / Public IP and VM Count

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I created a new ARM Template with conditions as parameter for private and public IP and VM count.

I can use a template with conditions for private and public IP, but not with VM count (copy) or I can use a template with VM count, but not with conditions.

In variable section I use the following code from GitHub https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-new-or-existing-conditions/azuredeploy.json for condition, for public or private IP:

```
"requirePublicIP":"[and(equals(parameters('NetworkInterfaceType'),'Public'),greater(parameters('PIPCount'),0))]",
                "publicIP1": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',Concat(variables('virtualMachineName')))]"
                    }
```

In resource section by networkInterfaces I use the follwing code from GitHub:

```
"publicIPAddress": "[if(variables('requirePublicIP'),variables('publicIP1'),json('null'))]"
```

Thats working fine, but I can't use no VM count (copy).

If I use VM count (copy) then use this code from GitHub  https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-copy-index-loops/azuredeploy.json:

```
"publicIPAddress":{
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',Concat(variables('virtualMachineName'),copyIndex(0),'-pip'))]"
                        }
```

Thats working fine, but I can't use the condition for public and privat IP.

How can I combine the conditions for public and private IP and VM count?

Comment: whats the issue? can you share the whole template? i dont see why this would not work

Comment: also, if you can share the error...

Comment: I use for condition the variable section and here must add copyindex for VM count. But I can't add copyindex in variable sections. The ID for PublicIP must also variable for public and private IP and VM Count.

Comment: I must here

"publicIPAddress":{
                            "id": ""
                        }
set the condition for public or private IP and VM count and that is not possible or? The error is in ARM that the id for publicIPAddress is not valid.

Comment: I need a possibility to generate the ID for the puplic IP with a condition for public or private IP:

"publicIPAddress": "[if(variables('requirePublicIP'),variables('publicIP1'),json('null'))]"

"publicIPAddress":{
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',Concat(variables('virtualMachineName'),copyIndex(0),'-pip'))]"
                        }

So I need a mix of both...

Comment: I have found a solution:
publicIPAddress": {
                                "id": "[if(variables('requirePublicIP'), resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',Concat(variables('virtualMachineName'),copyIndex(0),'-pip')),json('null'))]"
                            }